# Display Magento Custom Option Values in Shoping Cart

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

A few of the products on my Magento site have custom options (not attributes). For one product is available in Gold or Silver an it has a drop down with those two options.
How do I get the name of the option the user selected to show next to product name on the shopping cart page?

Comment: use session to save custom option and get it in shopping cart.

Answer (score 9):

To get product custom option value at cart page which are set at 'AddtoCart' time try with following code.

```
$cart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getQuote()->getAllItems();

/* cart item loop */
foreach($cart as $item) {

    /* This will get custom option value of cart item */
    $_customOptions = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());

    /* Each custom option loop */
    foreach($_customOptions['options'] as $_option){
        echo $_option['label'] .'=>'. $_option['value']."<br/>";
        // Do your further logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: thnx rakesh it was really life saver

Comment: how we can get price.?

Comment: how to get for a particular customer ?

Comment: how i can get the option price?

Answer (score 4):

Using the following code you can get product custom option values.

```
$productOptions= $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());
```

Comment: This is for simple product option not a configurable product correct?

Comment: I think this is for attributes not options

Comment: Hello Sam  try this it may help you! http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/65107/ OR http://www.richardcastera.com/blog/magento-add-a-product-with-custom-options-to-the-cart-through-url-querystring

Answer (score 2):

If you choose to go with  **Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable::getOrderOptions($product)** as suggested by others, make sure you don't call it on disabled products as in version CE 1.9.* (possibly in other versions, too) this leads to a nasty function call on null. Unless you haven't added a custom module that purges disabled products from carts, this can make your site crash for every customer who added a later disabled product to their cart.

Luckily, you don't need to worry about that if you're using or extending Magento's cart item renderer **Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer**. It offers method **getOptionList()** which will return an array of all selected options to you, custom options included:

```
//$this = Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer
$options = $this->getOptionList();
```

This method getOptionList() calls **Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_Configuration** which will be your answer if you're not using the Magento renderers or if you want a list of *only* custom options.

Here's an example of how you can get an array of the selected custom options by calling the helper directly:

```
$_item = $this->getItem(); // item can represent a simple, configurable or grouped product
$helper = Mage::helper('catalog/product_configuration');

if($onlyCustomOptions){
    // get an array of only custom options
    $options = $helper->getCustomOptions($_item);
} else {
   // get an array of configurable & custom options
    $options = $helper->getOptions($_item);
}
```

(Note: $options will be an empty array if the item has no options.)

Comment: Should be the accepted answer, simple and best usage of Magento way

Answer (score 1):

If not display then you should try this.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$options = $product->getProductOptions();
foreach ($options as $option){ print_r($option->getValues()); }
```

You will find options value

Comment: I placed this code in my loop at: default/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml and it did nothing except cut off remaining products.

Comment: try finding this code $_options = $this->getOptionList() in default/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml this fetch selected options for product in your cart page.

Answer (score 0):

Load the product using the following code:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
```

And then get the custom options with this:

```
$options = $product->getProductOptions();
```

Hope this was helpful,

Pesach

Comment: I have it in cart.pthml and it is not displaying the option on frontend:      `<th width="200" rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>"><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('Product Name') ?>
                        <?php $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$options = $product->getProductOptions();
?>

                        </span> 
                        
</th>`

Comment: maybe it needs to be echo'd out

Comment: Product options are display in cart page by default

Comment: Where in the .phtml files is this called out? I'm not seeing it

Comment: It's not you are going to add it (i'm assuming i'm misunderstanding your question)