# Magento Shopgram Checkout Page

Tags: java, php, wordpress, magento, zend-framework

Now I have read over dozen threads and even a dozen different web pages which have asked the similar question. However the responses did not work for me. I tried all of them. Also to note I could not comment on the questions hence the reason for this thread. To be as detailed as possible FROM what i can tell in the magento checkout is something to do with SHOPGRAM? It is my current checkout cart. I have two custom attributes called license_period and another called number_of_devices.

I need to add the two fields within the checkout cart. One thing to note is that is out of the testing i have done it seems the file cart_new.phtml located @ /app/design/frontend/shopgram/default/template/checkout controls the layout. this script i have tried editting I have tried alot however any change i make does not even appear. Even when i edit the default.phtml @/app/design/frontend/shopgram/default/template/checkout/cart/item It does not make any changes i have even deleted most of the files in these directorys and it causes no change to the content. Only the cart_new.phtml controls the content.

Now i do not know magento too well so i might be mistaken. However when i did try a lot of different queries and most of them do nothing. some of them cause the table to disapear.

The following are just a 2 out of the 100 links I have tried. However I can only post two links.

[Display Magento Custom Option Values in Shoping Cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11992413/display-magento-custom-option-values-in-shoping-cart?rq=1)

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5057/magento-checkout-getting-custom-attribute-value

Comment: To see which files you have to edit, enable Template Path Hints (System -> Configuration -> Developer) and reloading the frontend will show you the name and paths of the files used on a specific page. Besides that, be sure to clear the cache.

Comment: Thank you but I have already sorted the issue out. Took a lot of programming and testing lol

Comment: Then feel free to post the answer and mark the question as solved. :D

Comment: i posted it up thanks for the adivce @SamuelComan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this script Here incase anyone needs to know how to add custom attributes into your shopping cart.

```
/**
** This will load the product attributes. Now you can create a plugin to do this which will 
**help with performance however in my case the plugin was not working correctly.
**/

    <?php $_product= Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId()) ?> 



/**
**Use javascript to add the attribute into the correct location in the shopping cart.
**
**/

<script>

 var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('item-options'), last = elements.length - 1;

 elements[last].innerHTML = "<dt>Odkaz </dt><dd>Instalační soubor</dd>   <dt>No Of Devices:</dt> <dd><?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('number_of_devices')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?></dd>  <dt>License Period:</dt> <dd><?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('licence_period')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?></dd> ";
</script>
```

**PS**

You will find This script was placed in the cart_new.php which is located @app/design/frontend/shopgram/default/template/checkout.

Another piece of advice is that if you place this code anywhere in the script it will not work. So do not get fustrated if it does not work. It has to go somewhere where it will not block the other scripts from working. I placed mine within the the actual for each items as items loop where it draws the data for the shopping cart.